# How and where to invoke HeaderValueRouter and HeaderEnricher for jms or activemq with spring-integration

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-integration

In my project ,we use **spring-integration** to implement the queue. The configuration for Header-Value-Router is in the xml as below:

```
<header-value-router input-channel="jmsUVMasterMessageChannel"
    header-name="METADATA_TYPE" default-output-channel="nullChannel"
    resolution-required="false">
    <mapping value="ASSEMBLY" channel="downloadImageToS3Channel" />
    <mapping value="THIRDPARTY" channel="invokeUVMasterAPIChannel" />
</header-value-router>

<header-enricher input-channel="JuiceVendorMessageChannel"
    output-channel="JuiceHeaderEnricherChannel">
    <header name="sourceName" value="JUICE" />
</header-enricher>
```

And here is the gateway config:

I wanna know how to implement this config in java code? I searched google and found following code:

```
@Bean
public HeaderValueRouter headerRouter(String gatewayPrefix) {
  HeaderValueRouter router = new HeaderValueRouter("METADATA_TYPE");
  router.setChannelMapping("ASSEMBLY", "downloadImageToS3Channel");
  router.setChannelMapping("THIRDPARTY", "invokeUVMasterAPIChannel");
  router.setDefaultOutputChannel(new NullChannel());
  router.setResolutionRequired(false);
  return router;
}

@Bean
@Transformer(inputChannel="sdiVenderMessageChannel", outputChannel="sdiHeaderEnricherChannel")
public HeaderEnricher enrichHeaders() {
    Map<String, HeaderValueMessageProcessor<?>> headersToAdd = new HashMap<String, HeaderValueMessageProcessor<?>>();
    // TODO 
    //headersToAdd.put("sourceName",new StaticHeaderValueMessageProcessor<String>("SDI"));
    headersToAdd.put("sourceName", null);
    HeaderEnricher enricher = new HeaderEnricher(headersToAdd);
    if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
        logger.debug("HeaderEnricher bean initial!");
    }
    return enricher;
}
```

But here are my questions:

1) how to config the 'input-channel' in java config?

2) Where should I invoke this function? When I start the application , the code doesn't run into this function. I know the headerValueRouter is used to dispatcher the message from input-channel to the output-channel, but what's the exact place that I can invoke this router? In the ConnectionFactory or ListenerContainer?

And here is the gateway I defined:

```
public void registerDynamicInboundGateway(DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
    this.beanFactory = beanFactory;

    BeanDefinitionBuilder builder = BeanDefinitionBuilder
            .genericBeanDefinition("org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint");
    String jndiFactoryName = this.registerJndiObjectFactoryBean(gatewayPrefix, jmsQueueValue);
    this.destination = jndiFactoryName;
    String containerBeanName = this.registerMessageListenerContainer();
    String listenerBeanName = this.registerMessageListener();
    builder.addConstructorArgReference(containerBeanName);
    builder.addConstructorArgReference(listenerBeanName);
    setValueIfAttributeDefined(builder, autoStartup, "auto-startup");

    String beanName = null;
    if(gatewayPrefix.equals(HCC_GATEWAY_PREFIX)){
        beanName = gatewayPrefix + DynamicInboundGateway.HCC_GATEWAY_SUFIX;
    } else if (gatewayPrefix.equals(UVMASTER_GATEWAY_PREFIX)) {
        beanName = gatewayPrefix + DynamicInboundGateway.UVMASTER_GATEWAY_PREFIX;
    } else {
        beanName = gatewayPrefix + DynamicInboundGateway.GATEWAY_SUFIX;
    }

    this.beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(
            beanName, builder.getBeanDefinition());
}
```

I felt confused and didn't found any sample code for this.
Thanks a lot!

When I define the HeaderEnricher according to the sample code in the spring-integration website like below:

```
@Bean
@Transformer(inputChannel="sdiVenderMessageChannel", outputChannel="sdiHeaderEnricherChannel")
public HeaderEnricher enrichHeaders() {
    Map<String, HeaderValueMessageProcessor<?>> headersToAdd = new HashMap<String, HeaderValueMessageProcessor<?>>();
    // TODO 
    headersToAdd.put("sourceName",new StaticHeaderValueMessageProcessor<String>("SDI"));
    //headersToAdd.put("sourceName", null);
    HeaderEnricher enricher = new HeaderEnricher(headersToAdd);
    if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
        logger.debug("HeaderEnricher bean initial!");
    }
    return enricher;
}
```

And this occured some error:

```
StaticHeaderValueMessageProcessor cannot be resolved to a type
```

But I've import all the required packages with maven. I can not figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully, this simple Spring Boot app will make things clear...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So40585409Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(So40585409Application.class, args);
        JmsTemplate template = context.getBean(JmsTemplate.class);
        template.convertAndSend("foo", "message1", m -> {
            m.setStringProperty("foo", "bar");
            return m;
        });
        template.convertAndSend("foo", "message2", m -> {
            m.setStringProperty("foo", "baz");
            return m;
        });
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        context.close();
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint inbound(ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory) {
        return new JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint(container(jmsConnectionFactory), listener());
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory) {
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory);
        container.setDestinationName("foo");
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    public ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener listener() {
        ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener listener = new ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener();
        listener.setRequestChannelName("toRouter");
        return listener;
    }

    @Bean
    @Router(inputChannel="toRouter")
    public HeaderValueRouter router() {
        HeaderValueRouter router = new HeaderValueRouter("foo");
        router.setChannelMapping("bar", "barChannel");
        router.setChannelMapping("baz", "bazChannel");
        return router;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "barChannel")
    public void bar(String in) {
        System.out.println("Received via barChannel: " + in);
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "bazChannel")
    public void baz(String in) {
        System.out.println("Received via bazChannel: " + in);
    }

}
```

Result:

```
2016-11-14 09:17:56.798  INFO 65082 --- [           main] com.example.So40585409Application        : Started So40585409Application in 8.842 seconds (JVM running for 10.819)
Received via barChannel: message1
Received via bazChannel: message2
2016-11-14 09:18:02.038  INFO 65082 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2b546384: startup date [Mon Nov 14 09:17:49 EST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
```

**EDIT - Header Enricher**

I just added your bean with no problems...

```
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "barChannel2")
    public void bar(String in, @Header("sourceName") String sourceName) {
        System.out.println("Received via barChannel: " + in + " " + sourceName);
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "bazChannel")
    public void baz(String in) {
        System.out.println("Received via bazChannel: " + in);
    }

    @Bean
    @Transformer(inputChannel = "barChannel", outputChannel = "barChannel2")
    public HeaderEnricher enrichHeaders() {
        Map<String, HeaderValueMessageProcessor<?>> headersToAdd = new HashMap<String, HeaderValueMessageProcessor<?>>();
        headersToAdd.put("sourceName", new StaticHeaderValueMessageProcessor<String>("SDI"));
        HeaderEnricher enricher = new HeaderEnricher(headersToAdd);
        return enricher;
    }
```

Result:

```
2016-11-15 09:00:48.383  INFO 50137 --- [           main] com.example.So40585409Application        : Started So40585409Application in 1.814 seconds (JVM running for 2.528)
Received via barChannel: message1 SDI
Received via bazChannel: message2
2016-11-15 09:00:53.424  INFO 50137 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2c34f934: startup date [Tue Nov 15 09:00:46 EST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That really make thing clearly. But one more question, when I defined the HeaderEnricher , I 've update my question, could you please help to look into this? Thanks again.

Comment: I just added your bean to my test case (see edit) with no problems. Of course, you need `import org.springframework.integration.transformer.support.StaticHeaderValueMessageProcessor;` which has been available since Spring Integration 3.0.